# Link pfsense networks (bridge, vlan)

Tags: networking, pfsense

I've got two pfsense instances with the same networks configured (both works with 192.168.1.0/24 and there are no ip conflicts). Both of them works in different networks (WANs). Here's the little scetch:

[image: Scetch of my networks]

What's the easiest way to connect from pf1 to pf2 with using the NAT's addresses (let's say I would like to be able to ping 192.168.1.35 from 192.168.1.12)?

Sadly I'm new in pfsense and i have no idea how to do it. Could you help me please?

Comment: Sounds like what you need is a Site-to-site VPN or a GRE Tunnel. I'm sure if you do some research on those topics, you'll find what you need.

Comment: I had to reconfigure a lot of things before setting the vpn but in the end it works. Thank you very much :)

Comment: No problem! Let me add that comment as an answer. I would appreciate it if you marked it as correct. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you need is a Site-to-site VPN or a GRE tunnel. I'm not too terribly familiar with setting them up, so you'll have to do some research on how to do that. But, once you get it working you'll be able to send traffic between the two networks as if they were connected directly to each other.